# PsExec with Get-WinEvent: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows-10, powershell, psexec

I'm trying to run `Get-WinEvent` on a remote PC using `psexec` but I'm getting the following error:

```
PS C:\> psexec \\pc28 Get-WinEvent -?
Starting Get-EventLog on pc28...
PsExec could not start Get-EventLog on pc28:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

However, if I run the same command locally on the other PC it runs fine:

```
PS C:\> Get-WinEvent -?

NAME
    Get-WinEvent

SYNTAX
    Get-WinEvent [[-LogName] <string[]>]...
(etc.)
```

It appears that I can run other commands on the remote PC like `systeminfo` and `wmic` but none of the `Get-*` commands.

Both the local and remote PCs are running Windows 10 and PowerShell 5.1. I've tried running `psexec` version 2.2 and 2.33 on the local PC. (Curiously, version 2.2 gives the error above while version 2.33 gives a logon failure message even with administrator credentials.)

**ANSWER**: As Robert pointed out in the comments below, `psexec` is for running executables, not PowerShell commands. See the marked answer below for how to do the same thing but with `Invoke-Command` and `PSRemoting` instead.

Comment: `Get-WinEvent` is a PowerShell command. ps-exec however can only run executables (.exe files) present on the target PC or a network drive.

Comment: @Robert - I see, thanks! Is there another way I can run Get-* commands remotely?

Comment: See the existing questions on that topic on ps-exec+powershell, e.g. https://superuser.com/questions/891519

Comment: Must you even use psexec and instead take it out of the loop and run `Invoke-Command -Computer pc28 -Scriptblock { Get-WinEvent -? }`

Comment: @Robert - That's what I needed, thanks!

Comment: PSRemoting is certainly the ideal option. However, you can run POwerShell via PSExec.exe, you just need to call it through the PowerShell.exe program. Here is an example: `PSExec.exe \\computer powershell.exe -c “Get-WinEvent”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `psexec` to run PowerShell commands remotely against other machines. Ensure that the remote machine has [PSRemoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.1) enabled and then run PowerShell commands against the remote machine using [invoke-command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html).

### [Enable-PSRemoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting?view=powershell-7.1) on remote machine

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

### Running remote PowerShell commands

```
Invoke-Command -Computer pc28 -Scriptblock { Get-WinEvent -? }
```

### Supporting Resources

- [Enable-PSRemoting](https://ss64.com/ps/enable-psremoting.html)
- [Invoke-Command](https://ss64.com/ps/invoke-command.html)

  > `-ScriptBlock scriptblock`
  >
  > The commands to run.
  >
  > Enclose the commands in curly braces `{ }` to
  > create a script block. This parameter is required.